# MATH PUZZLE ABOUT SEQUENCE

Tags: mathematics, number-sequence

In the array of numbers below, each number above the bottom row is equal to three times the number immediately below it. What is the value of x+y?

```
        27      x     81     -108
        9      -18    27     -36
        3      -6     y      -12
        1      -2     3      -4
```

Comment: This seems extremely simple and not really a puzzle...

Comment: Too simple for a puzzle, took me about 20 sec to calculate the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Er...

> y = 9, x = -54, x + y = **-45**. Not much else I can say...

Answer (score 0):

Is it:

> -549, because you wrote the code in JavaScript?